# Linq null error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

Coding up a statistics page for my website. I am using Linq with entity framework. I have a couple queries that work, but can't handle null exceptions. Just wondering if there is a way around it without having to readjust coding approach.

```
        var countriesElse = db.Profiles
            .GroupBy(av => av.Country)
            .Select(g => new { Country = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
        var otherCount = countriesElse
            .Where(x => x.Country != "US" && x.Country != "CA").FirstOrDefault();

        ViewBag.otherCount = otherCount.Count;
```

This throws a null error because there is nothing to select with this where clause, but I will be needing this query for future purposes because eventually it will be used.

Cheers

Comment: Store the result in a variable and check if that variable is `null` or not, act appropriately.

Comment: change to ViewBag.otherCount = otherCount ?? 0; instead? Edit: or use the answer below!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
if(otherCount != null)
   ViewBag.otherCount = otherCount.Count;

else ViewBag.otherCount = 0;
```

`Select` or `Where` will not throw a `NullReferenceException` if you don't try to access a property or method of *null* object in the query.Your problem is about the last line.

Also you can simplify your code using `FirstOrDefault` with a *predicate*:

```
 var profile = db.Profiles
        .GroupBy(av => av.Country)
        .Select(g => new { Country = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Country != "US" && x.Country != "CA");

ViewBag.otherCount = profile== null ? 0 : profile.Count;
```